# How to check List<> Contains with comparison on TimeSpan

Tags: asp.net, list, timespan

Ive got a list of TimeSpans and I need to check if any of them are more than 5 hrs. I know I could just loop through the list, but if its possible I'd prefer to check for the condition using one of the built in functions for List<>.

```
if (driverSchedules.GetAllShifts().Contains(delegate(TimeSpan ts) { return ts > new TimeSpan(5,0,0);}))
{
    return true;
}
```

*GetAllShifts returns a List.

The error I'm getting says:

```
"Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.TimeSpan' because it is not a 
delegate type"
```

As far as I can tell the "delegate type" is `System.TimeSpan`

Answer (score 3):

1.: [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) doesn't take a delegate as an argument; it wants a specific TimeSpan value.

2.: Since you want to find out whether *any* item in the collection matches a particular condition, use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx); it accepts a delegate.

```
return driverSchedules.GetAllShifts().Any(ts => ts > new TimeSpan(5,0,0));
```

Comment: Probably want to explain why TimeSpan isn't a delegate?

Answer (score -1):

The `Contains()` you are using expects a TimeSpan object as a parameter, not a delegate type. You want to use the `Any<>` extension which accepts a delegate custom comparer.

```
if (driverSchedules.GetAllShifts().Any<TimeSpan>((ts) => { return ts > new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0); }))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Won't a Where or Any clause be appropriate?

Comment: Any and Where seem implicitly the same. Where is more expensive, returning the actual list of elements that satisfy condition x.

Comment: @canon Apologies, I meant Contains.

Comment: @canon What version of .NET are you using? It is a LINQ extension. I have been using it from .NET 3.5+.

Comment: @canon Ah, my bad. It is `Any`. `Contains` and `Any` have the same overloads and highly similar text.